# Force file explorer to open in foreground with keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

elementary friends !

I installed PCManFM and added a keyboard shortcut (Special + E) to launch it, in system settings->keyboard->shortcuts->custom

Most of the time, if I have the focus on some program window,
the file explorer will launch in the background.

I would want it to come upfront.

I set the shortcut with a simple command 'pcmanfm'.
Would you know if I could use a command that forces it to start in the foreground ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that works fine for me:

[A convenient bash script](https://github.com/siliconchaos/bash-scripts/blob/master/ActivateOrLaunch.sh) that either launches a program or brings to front its first window. (*Also had to install a little keyboard tool called xdotool, used by the script*)

I then defined the bash script to be launched as a keyboard shortcut :)